# Cant create a 3d plane using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning how to create a plane in three.js using this tut:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU9UABZSAoc&index=2&list=PLcUid3OP_4OVX8zp-ZTcyOsp6C9CJCqd0

The code I have written is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="loadPlane()">
    <canvas id="gl" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadPlane() {
            // body...

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer ();
            renderer.setSize (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild (renderer.domElement);

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.y = -400;
            camera.position.z = 400;
            camera.rotation.x = .75;

            var scene = new THREE.scene ();
            var plane = new THREE.Mesh (new THREE.PlaneGeometry (300, 300), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial ());
            scene.add (plane);
            renderer.render (scene, camera);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is not working. The output is just a black screen. What is wrong with it? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
var scene = new THREE.scene ();
```

should be

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene ();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Cant believe I overlooked such a simple thing :)

Comment: @lisbeth This happens :) Sometimes see what happens in JavaScript console of your browser

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rotation you have on the camera you might be seeing the backside of the plane, in which case you will see anything. You can change that by doing:

```
new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
```

look at the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/4oaxxpk1/